# Internet Explorer IE11 launches in Enhanced Security for Users despite setting in Server Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-explorer

Our users log on to an RDP server running Windows 2008 R2. I have already gone into Server Manager and disabled ESC for both admins and users. While the setting is applied for admins, users still go into ESC when they launch IE11. I've already checked the registry settings and they reflect the appropriate settings from the Server Manager.

What else can cause users to launch into ESC?

Can a user tell IE to start without ESC?

Comment: Do you have any group policy objects forcing IE ESC on?

Comment: @MichaelHampton not that I know of, but where is that policy set?

Comment: Domain Controller.  Look in the Group Policy Management tool or run rsop/gpresult from the command line on the server in question.  And as an aside, users should not be logging into servers directly, and they certainly should not be running a web browser from it.  Sounds to me like you have bigger issues than IE ESC.

Comment: @HopelessN00b, this is an RDP server, where users go to work from home as an alternative to VPN. Also, I was asking specifically _which_ GPO setting is responsible for ESC. As far as I can tell there is not one out there.

Comment: [Check this thread for your GPO options.](http://4sysops.com/archives/disable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-ie-esc-with-group-policy/)

Comment: @HopelessN00b thanks for the link - I should have mentioned I saw that already. The problem is that those registry settings are _already_ set on the RDP server, so mandating them through group policy would have no effect...

Comment: Have you checked rsop and gpresult for those users?  Could be a different policy taking precedence for the users in question.

Comment: Yes - but I am now wondering, as a user (not admin), is there a way to tell whether I am in IE ESC?

Comment: @HopelessN00b I ended up deleting the `IsInstalled` key and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I used the Server Manager and the Registry Editor to ensure `IsInstalled` was `0` (see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e12693b3-c3e7-450e-8dfc-3b5bca29ce96/disable-ie-enhanced-security-does-not-work-rdssession-host-2008-r2?forum=winserverTS) it still didn't take.

However, deleting the `IsInstalled` key entirely for the user registry setting did work after I logged off and on again.

Comment: maybe you just needed to log off after setting to 0?

Comment: Exact same problem here.  It was definitely disabled, I tried enabling and disabling again through Server Manager, nothing.  Deleting the setting and logging in again resolved it for me.